# Netbeans Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a weird error when executing a Java project on Netbeans. I have the following function that is executed in main:

```
public ArrayList<String> getPlayersName(){
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int players;

    System.out.println("Number of players:");
    players = in.nextInt();

    for(int i=0; i<players; i++){
        System.out.println("Player name:");
        String s = in.next();
        list.add(s);
    }

    return list;
}
```

When I execute the project, I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
```

The input I give in is as simple as: 2, a, b. Curious thing is that sometimes, with the same arguments, the program executes normally.

Main program:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    QytetetTextView ui = new QytetetTextView();
    controller.setPlayersName(ui.getPlayersName());

    int chosenOp, casillaElegida = 0;
    boolean needChooseBox;
    do {
        chosenOp = ui.elegirOperacion();
        System.out.println(controller.getEstado());
        needChooseBox = controller.needChoseBox(chosenOp);
        if (needChooseBox)
            casillaElegida = ui.chooseBox(chosenOp);
        if (!needChooseBox || chosenBox >= 0)
            System.out.println(controlador.runOp(chosenOp, chosenBox));
    } while (1 == 1);
}
```

Comment: The code in your question will not throw  a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, there must be some other code which is causing this.

Comment: @d3vcho Put your main method code please

Comment: @Mark Hi Mark, thanks for your quick answer. The problem is, that behaviour doesn't always happen. It's just sometimes, so I'm sure the program works as expected. That's almost the first thing that is called in main function, so I can't really tell.

Comment: @d3vcho We can't really tell either then, there must be some other place where this happens

Comment: @RafałSokalski Done :)

Comment: @Mark Any suggestions on how to debug this? I'm working with a few classes and packages, so I can't really paste everything here.

Comment: @d3vcho There should be a stacktrace which is longer than the one you've already posted, which identifies where the error exactly occurred

Comment: Put breakpoint on this line controller.setPlayersName(ui.getPlayersName()) and step over one line and check if exception is thrown. Please put also controller class

Comment: @Mark Appeared a new error on Netbeans before introducing anything: Note: /home/d3vcho/NetBeansProjects/QytetetJava/src/modeloqytetet/Qytetet.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.